# UnityWebRequest byte array

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine

I am trying to send, with each frame captured by the webcam, the image bytes using a post request to be processed in a NodeJS API.

Using this code:

```
Debug.Log(imageBytes.Length); //Prints a number
    Debug.Log(imageBytes); //Prints the array type (?)
    Debug.Log(imageBytes[1]); //Prints the byte

    UnityWebRequest www = new UnityWebRequest(url, UnityWebRequest.kHttpVerbPOST);
        UploadHandlerRaw handler = new UploadHandlerRaw(imageBytes);
        handler.contentType= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        www.uploadHandler = handler;
        Debug.Log(www.uploadHandler.data[1]);
        www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();

        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        string jsonResponse = www.downloadHandler.text;
        Debug.Log(jsonResponse);
```

However, when I do a `console.log`, in the API, of the `req.body` it prints

> {}

. Apparently, the data isn't being sended by the `UnityWebRequest`.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: How about if you log req.files?

Comment: I'm using the express framework. The mentioned property does not exist on the req parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way of getting this working.

Need to change the code in the Unity to:

```
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, webForm))
            {
        www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        www.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(imageBytes);
        www.uploadHandler.contentType = "text/html";
        www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            }
```

And in Node.JS to:

```
app.use(cors());
var options = {
    inflate: true,
    limit: '3000kb',
    type: 'text/html'
  };
app.use(bodyParser.raw(options));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong content type for binary data. If you use the WWWForm class, it will automatically set this header to multipart/form-data. Try this code:

```
    var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
    wwwForm.AddBinaryData ("image", imageBytes, "imagedata.raw");
    var request = UnityWebRequest.Post (url, wwwForm);
    yield return request.SendWebRequest ();
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it have the same result. I think the problem is in the reception of the data form NodeJS.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried slightly new webrequest class couple of months ago and I had a similar problem while posting data to server, then I switched back to the old www class to handle it and it worked like a charm.

Comment: The thing is, it sends the data out of unity. But it won't get to NodeJS. even if i do the POST in Postman it won't get there. So, I think the problem is in the Node and not in the Unity.